# How to specify headers for a web request

Tags: f#, http-headers, http-get, request-headers

Trying to set headers for a http call but running into issues. Need guidance for both `Authorization` and a custom header `x-api-key`.

```
let url = "http://example.com"
let token = requestToken()

let request = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
request.Method <- "GET"
request.Accept <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
request.Headers.Authorization <- sprintf "%s %s" token.token_type token.access_token
request.Headers["x-api-key"] <- "api-key" // custom headers

// or this

request.Headers["Authorization"] <- sprintf "%s %s" token.token_type token.access_token
```

The error I'm getting is

> error FS3217: This expression is not a function and cannot be applied. Did you intend to access the indexervia expr.[index] instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message that you are getting actually tells you what the problem is. In F#, the syntax for using an indexer is `obj.[idx]` - you need to have a `.` between the object and the square bracket. The correct syntax in your specific case would be:

```
request.Headers.["x-api-key"] <- "api-key"
request.Headers.["Authorization"] <- sprintf "%s %s" token.token_type token.access_token
```

Comment: thanks for the correction. `request.Headers.Authorization <- sprintf "%s %s" token.token_type token.access_token` is wrong all the way, right?

Comment: Yes. `request.Headers.Authorization` does not work, because the `WebHeaderCollection` class does not include an `Authorization` property.

Comment: Thanks Shaun... linking doc for the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection(v=vs.110).aspx